# Not getting third character from right from the string in c#

Tags: c#, int

Here if my usename is Rus7AE then i want to take the number value i.e. third character from right. t.e. 7. Following code is not returning me the value 7 ?

studentA consists of 5-7th std studentB consists of 8-10th std studentC consists of 5-10th std thats common group but doesnt contains same values from studentA and studentB

```
private void authcheck()
        {
            username = Session["stud"].ToString();
            schlName = Session["stuschname"].ToString();

        string value = username.ToString();
        int groupName = Convert.ToInt32(value[value.Length - 3]);            

        Session["grpName"] = groupName.ToString();
}
```

How can i get the thirdlast value

Comment: Which `groupNames` should end up in the third case? All numbers you put there already match earlier cases.

Comment: studentA consists of 5-7th std
studentB consists of 8-10th std
studentC consists of 5-10th std thats common group but doesnt contains same values from studentA and studentB

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, but with your code *nothing* will be put into studentC.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Infact u r right.. can u show me a way with it ?

Comment: No I can't, since I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But since it's not a good question, I won't upvote it either.

Comment: @CodesInChaos My account is locked hence i am not able to post new questions.. If you upvote for me i will be very thankful to you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert a character to a numeric value, which will not give the intended result.

Try

```
int groupName = int.Parse(value.Substring(value.Length - 3, 1));
```

If it is possible that you will receive data not in this format, look at [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead.

Convert.ToInt32 is not working because it takes the actual value of the character based on the current encoding and converts that to a character.  For example,

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32('7');
```

Yields 55, which is the ASCII or UTF-8 code for '7'.

Comment: This will still throw an exception if the substring is not numeric.  They should use TryParse().

Comment: @PeterGluck: Yes I reference that in my answer.  May have added that after your comment though.

Comment: @PeterGluck The correct choice depends on the context. It's not clear from the OP which one fits here.

Comment: On the other hand, `Convert.ToInt32("7")` returns `7`

Comment: I could not say as I didn't downvote you.  You could have made the question clearer by focusing just on the one line that was causing problems (where you try to grab the numeric digit and convert it to an integer).  Perhaps the extra information caused people to find the question unfocused.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get third last value because the conditions are wrong

```
if
    5-7
else if
    8-10
else if 
    5-10
```

Last one will never be hit in this case

Comment: What you are saying is *also true* but not the reason he's failing to get a "7".

Comment: That's not related to the question that was asked. This should be a comment

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is how I got the question, he cannot get into the last `else if` (which is third)

Comment: "Third last value" refers to the third character from the end of the string `value`.

Comment: OP's stated issue is "Following code is not returning me the value 7"

Answer (score 0):

since you can have "10" in your group-number (as i've seen in your code) and maybe some dual-digits more (11,12,13 etc.) we should use Regular Expressions here...

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\w+(\d+)\w+");

int groupNumber;
var match = regex.Match(subjectString);
if(!match.Success || !match.Groups[1].Success || !int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out groupNumber))
    throw new Exception("Student has no group!?!?");

string groupName = null;
switch(groupNumber){
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
        groupName = "studentA";
    break;

    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        groupName = "studentB";
    break;

    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        groupName = "studentC";
    break;

    default:
        throw new Exception("invalid group number");
}
```